# Проблема с intent (String to File)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Нужно запустить интент, но не с url, а уже готовым файлом, но предоставленным в виде текста (torrent файл открыли через текстовый редактор и скопировали данный текст). setData просит Uri, а Uri либо строку либо файл.

Как конвертировать строку в файл, **не сохраняя его** на сд карте или телефоне? Или можно как иначе запустить интент?

Upd

Ссылка отдает тип Content-Type  application/x-bittorrent. Но что бы запрос прошел успешно, нужно указать Referer. По это просто передать ссылку в торрент клиент не получиться. Я правильно понял что нужно программно создать торрент файл и передавать его?

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос попонятней. Что Вы хотите? Положить текст в интент и что бы он открылся в каком-нибудь текстовом редакторе, или в Вашем же приложении, но в другой активити, или как?

Comment: сам текст это .torrent файл, но только его открыли с помощью текстового редактора и положили на сервер. Я его спарсил и теперь мне нужно открыть его через x-bittorrent приложение

Comment: Вобщем-то формирование интента зависит от целевого приложения, для торрент клиента скорее всего нужен торрент-файл или ссылка на него. И что значит "открыли в редакторе"? Текст встроен в какую-то страницу, или Вы просто вычитали его как текст? В любом случае записать его в локальный файл - плёвое дело.